# How do we say "right back at you"?

Tags: translation, phrase-request

When someone is wishing us something, how do we say "right back at you"?

Is "lo stesso vale per te" the right and only response?

Answer (score 8):

*Lo stesso vale per te* va più che bene ed è di uso comune; come suggerisce l'utente @Bakuriu, forme diffuse sono *anche a te* o *anche tu*, che talora suonano meglio:

> *«Auguri di buon Natale!» «Grazie, anche a te!»* 
>  *«Divertiti!» «Anche tu!»*.

*[Altrettanto](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/altrettanto/)* è una buona alternativa:

> [...] come risposta a un augurio: *«Buon appetito!» «Grazie, altrettanto»*.

Comment: I would even say that *Altrettanto* (lit. *similarly*) is the most idiomatic choice.

Comment: I agree with Denis: *lo stesso vale per te* sounds a bit stilted, or so informal as to sound insincere.

Comment: I believe *anche a te* / *anche tu* generally sounds better than *lo stesso vale per te*. For example: *Auguri di Buon Natale!*, reply: *Anche a te!* or an other example: *Divertitevi!*, reply: *Anche tu!*.

Comment: Potresti includere nella risposta le alternative di @Bakuriu?

Comment: @Charo subito. Grazie a tutti per i suggerimenti.

Comment: I would use _altrettanto_ just when the other person is starting the wishing with _buon_ or _buona_ and the same wish could be said to the other person. For example, if I am going for a walk, and that person tells me _buona passeggiata_, I don't reply _altrettanto_ if that person is going at home to cook lunch.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I agree, but then this is also the usage of "right back at you", isn't it?

Comment: @DenisNardin I think _right back at you_ is also said when somebody is offending you.